# Using `DATE()` in Doctrine Querybuilder

Tags: date, datetime, doctrine-orm, doctrine, query-builder

I need to get all rows where `DATE(a.when)` matches the string `2014-09-30`.

```
$builder = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
$builder->select('a')
        ->from('Entity\Appointment', 'a')
        ->andWhere('a.when = :date')
        ->setParameter('date', $date);
```

`a.when` is a full `DATETIME`; `:date` is only a `string` (in `DATE` format).

The following and variations didn't work:

```
        ->andWhere('DATE(a.when) = :date')

Error: Expected known function, got 'DATE'
```

What's the correct usage here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Doctrine 2 - Filter results by a datetime field's date part](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10824383/doctrine-2-filter-results-by-a-datetime-fields-date-part)

Comment: @andy not a duplicate. I'm using the **queryBuilder** and the error message using `createQuery` and the `queryBuilder` is the same: `Error: Expected known function, got 'DATE'`.

Comment: The erro is the same because there is no `DATE()` in DQL. If you use the WHERE clause from the linked duplicate, your approach should work as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This actually is a very common question. 
It turns out that not all sql databases support a DATE function, so the good people in charge of Doctrine decided not to support it nativelly.

Kind of wish they did because it would have saved a bunch of people a fair amount of effort.

So add this rather magical class to your project:

```
namespace Cerad\Bundle\CoreBundle\Doctrine\DQL;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;

class Date extends FunctionNode
{
    public $date;

    public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return "DATE(" . $sqlWalker->walkArithmeticPrimary($this->date) . ")";
    }
    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);

        $this->date = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();

        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }
}
```

Then wire it up in the doctrine section of your app/config.yml:

```
doctrine:
  orm:
  default_entity_manager:       default
  auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%

  entity_managers:

    default:
      connection: default
      ...
      dql:
        datetime_functions:
          date:  Cerad\Bundle\CoreBundle\Doctrine\DQL\Date
```

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html

There are other bundles out there with more sql functions.  Oddly enough, the first time I looked a few years ago,  none of them had Date defined.  So I just made my own.

====================================================================

Update 01

I did not check the tags carefully and assumed that this was a Symfony 2 application.  The Date class stays the same.  You wire it up by getting the doctrine configuration object.

```
$config = new \Doctrine\ORM\Configuration();
$config->addCustomDatetimeFunction('DATE', 'blahblah\Date');
```

Check the Doctrine link for details.

Comment: I give you an upvote for your effort, unfortunately I cannot change our core libs like Doctrine. I am going with a non-DQL way now until I find a better way.

Comment: You are not changing the core library.  You are just adding a custom function.  Nothing inside of Doctrine is being changed.

Comment: I can't get it "wired up". I don't have this config file. I tried with `YEAR()`, `DAY()` and `MONTH()` now because their class files were already there but the error is accordingly the same..

Comment: See my update.  Just add it to your Doctrine configuration object.

Comment: Ah ok this time it's working, we got Doctrine hooked into ZF1.

Comment: I've come here because I've implemented DATE() pretty much identically to you but it's returning a string rather than a DateTime... is there some configuration option we have missed?

Comment: @AndyPreston Always fun to see old threads still active.  This thread is about using the mysql DATE function in a DQL query.  Nothing to do with what is ultimately returned.  Check your entity mappings.  Try to simplify your query as much as possible.  If you still have issues then consider opening a new question.

Answer (score 15):

Thanks to andy, using this now:

```
$builder = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
$builder->select('a')
        ->from('Entity\Appointment', 'a')
        ->andWhere('a.when >= :date_start')
        ->andWhere('a.when <= :date_end')
        ->setParameter('date_start', $date->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00'))
        ->setParameter('date_end',   $date->format('Y-m-d 23:59:59'));
```

Comment: Answer is incorrect.

Both a.when where caluses should use closed intervals (>= & <=).

Using code above - rows with 23:59:59 and 00:00:00 will NEVER get selected.

Comment: @Arkadiusz'flies'Rzadkowolski so you are downvoting because I made `<` instead of `<=` ? This minor detail is not affecting the implementation itself which was perfectly legit in 2014 and is still in 2019.

Comment: I have edited your answer & removed downvote.

But I disagree it's minor detail. Closed / Open intervals make a big deal in real life :)

Comment: This should be `<` with `$date->modify('+1 day')->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00')` as the database may or may not consider microseconds which could mean a `date_end` on 23:59:59:200 is not considered.

Answer (score 3):

A different approach using $qb->expr()->between() in the same andWhere:

```
    $builder = $this->em->createQueryBuilder(); $builder->select('a')
                ->from('Entity\Appointment', 'a')
                ->andWhere($qb->expr()->between('a.when', ':date_start', ':date_end'))
                ->setParameter('date_start', $date->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00'))
                ->setParameter('date_end',   $date->format('Y-m-d 23:59:59'));
```

Comment: can you add a bit of an explanation to the code you are sharing, what you are doing, and how it is a different approach ?