# Get data between dates php symfony mongodb

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-3.4

I save the information in a mongodb database, one of the fields is "date" in isodate format.
ISODate ("2019-11-22T10: 57: 47.000-05: 00"), how can I get a consultation with doctrine, version 3.4 of symfony, where I can bring the data between November 20 and 22.

I tried the following two options, but they don't work

```
$dataPay = $docPay->createQueryBuilder('AppBundle:TransactionPaymentez')
            ->field('date')->gte('2019-11-20')
            ->field('date')->lte('2019-11-22');

$dataPay = $docPay->createQueryBuilder('AppBundle:TransactionPaymentez')
            ->field('date')
            ->range('2019-11-20', '2019-11-22');

$dataPay = $dataPay->getQuery()->execute();
```

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34872032/6127393

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare dates between datetimes with Doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29918007/compare-dates-between-datetimes-with-doctrine)