# Doctrine FindOneBy with exact DateTime return null

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two tables, `orders` and `appointment`

```sql
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `id_buyer` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_seller` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `reference` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_appointment` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `creation_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `paid_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `fulfilled_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `returned_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE `appointment` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `id_owner` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_customer` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `start` datetime NOT NULL,
  `end` datetime NOT NULL,
  `online` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `participant_number` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `status` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `creation_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Both of these tables were created automatically by Symfony & doctrine, using entities.

When I try to create a custom sql query everything works fine :

```sql
SELECT `id`, `id_owner`, `id_customer`, `start`  FROM `appointment` WHERE `id_owner` = 20 AND `id_customer` = 1 AND `start` = '2020-06-06 10:00:00'
```

```
+-----+----------+-------------+---------------------+
| id  | id_owner | id_customer | start               |
+-----+----------+-------------+---------------------+
| 763 |       20 |           1 | 2020-06-06 10:00:00 |
+-----+----------+-------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, here is my problem, when I do the same as the query above, but using findOneBy from doctrine, it returns null.

```php
$a = $repo->findOneBy(['start'=> $order->getFirstAppointment(), 'owner' => $order->getSeller(), 'customer' => $order->getBuyer()]);
var_dump($a);
var_dump($o->getFirstAppointment());
var_dump($order->getSeller()->getId());
var_dump($order->getBuyer()->getId());
```

Here is the var_dump output

```
ExampleController.php:390:null

ExampleController.php:391:
object(DateTime)[2692]
  public 'date' => string '2020-06-16 10:00:00.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)

ExampleController.php:392:int 20

ExampleController.php:393:int 1
```

When I don't use a date, everything works fine however, I need to use the date. My guess is, it's because of the date `'2020-06-16 10:00:00.000000'` that has some zero's at the end but, when I looked into the database, the ".000000" is not displayed anywhere.

```sql
mysql> SELECT `first_appointment` FROM orders WHERE id = 13;
+---------------------+
| first_appointment   |
+---------------------+
| 2020-06-16 10:00:00 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Does anyone knows how to fix the problem without using doctrine ? Also, I would love to understand why it's not working, it's driving me crazy.

For completeness, I'm using :

- PHP 7.4.3
- doctrine/common 3.0.2
- Symfony v5.0.11

I've also looked into similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29918007/compare-dates-between-datetimes-with-doctrine/29918391) but they're using a date BETWEEN and not an exact match.

Comment: This might be a typo in your question rather than your code, but your sample database row shows 2020-06-**0**6, and your DateTime object shows 2020-06-**1**6. If you try `findOneBy` with *only* the date parameter, do you get any results?

Comment: No that was it I was going mad because of a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens if you use scalar values. So the direct id and datetime in string format

```
$a = $repo->findOneBy([
    'start'=> $order->getFirstAppointment()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 
    'owner' => $order->getSeller()->getId(), 
    'customer' => $order->getBuyer()->getId()
]);
```

Or use DQL for more control

```
$query = $em->createQuery( 'SELECT u FROM Namespace\\EntityName u WHERE u.start = :start AND u.owner = :owner AND u.customer = :customer' );
                    
$query->setParameters([
     'start' => $order->getFirstAppointment()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') ,
     'owner' => $order->getSeller()->getId(),
     'customer' => $order->getBuyer()->getId()

 ]);
$result = $query->getResult();
```

---

As a quick tip. It is probably a better idea to use the ID keys for the relation mapping. In Order you would use one-to-one relation from Order to appointment ID instead of the date.

Comment: Could not convert PHP value '2020-06-16 10:00:00' of type 'string' to type 'datetime'. Expected one of the following types: null, DateTime

Comment: Are you set on using findOneBy? You could use dql . I will update my answer with an example

Comment: Using the DQL version give me an empty array as $result. `array (size=0)
  empty`. I've change the query to `'SELECT a FROM App\\Entity\\Appointment a WHERE a.start = :start AND a.owner = :owner AND a.customer = :customer'`. Oh and I can't use 1-1 relation because... it's quite long and complicated.

Comment: Have you verified the data in your database. are the dates the same?  ( looking at what iainn  commented on your post ) your appointment->start being 2020-06-06 10:00:00 and your order->first_appointment being 2020-06-16 10:00:00